# MVC 6 VNext How to set same layout from different areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to set same layout from different areas in MVC 6 Vnext,

I am using _ViewImports.cshmlt and _ViewStart.cshtml in each area

in _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Cross2Enterprise.Administrador
@using Cross2Enterprise.Administrador.Models
@using Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm only discarting the obvious things... Did you tried with ...? (I only have viewed a few of things about VNext )

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this is your scenario:

1. ASP.NET Core w/ MVC
2. Using an `\Areas` folder
3. You want to set the template used by all areas in one location

To do this have the following project layout:

```
\Areas\Home
\Areas\Home\Controllers
\Areas\Home\Views
\Areas\_ViewStart.cshtml
\Views
\Views\Shared\
\Views\Shared\_Layout1.cshtml
\Views\Shared\_Layout2.cshtml
```

Then in the file `\Areas\_ViewStart.cshtml` you can have the following:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout1";
}
```

This will make all views in all areas use `\Views\Shared\_Layout1.cshtml`.

NOTE: You can *NOT* put `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the following locations:

```
\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml
\Views\Shared\_ViewStart.cshtml
```

NOTE: You *CAN* put `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the following location:

```
\Areas\Home\_ViewStart.cshtml
```

NOTE: This also applies to _ViewImports.cshtml